# Prove that $\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N} a_{j}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N} b_{j}\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{2 N} c_{j}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Assume that $\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} a_{j}\right)$ and $\left(\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} b_{j}\right)$ are two absolutely convergent series.
We define $c_{n}=\sum_{j=0}^{n} a_{j} b_{n-j}$

Assume there exists $N \in \mathbb{ N }$  such that $a_{n}=b_{n}=0$ for all $n>N$.
Prove that $\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N} a_{j}\right)\left(\sum_{j=0}^{N} b_{j}\right)=\sum_{j=0}^{2 N} c_{j}$

**What I have tried**

I've tried to work with the fact that they are absolutely convergent and with the triangle inequality but I am arriving nowhere. I have also tried change of indexes but no luck. How should I approach this?

Comment: Change of indices definitely works. Or, if you have a statement about natural numbers, you can always try a mathematical induction.

Comment: You don't need any properties of absolute convergence. These sums are finite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the definition of the Cauchy product, we get

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{2N} c_k
= \sum_{k=0}^{2N} \sum_{i=0}^{k} a_i b_{k-i}
= \sum_{k=0}^{2N} \sum_{i+j=k} a_i b_j
= \sum_{i+j\leq 2N} a_i b_j. $$

However, by using the fact that $a_i = 0$ and $b_j = 0$ for $i, j > N$, we can freely introduce the extra conditions $i \leq N$ and $j \leq N$ to the last sum. So

$$
= \sum_{\substack{i, j \leq N \\ i+j \leq 2N}} a_i b_j
= \sum_{i, j \leq N} a_i b_j
= \left( \sum_{i=0}^{N} a_i \right)\left( \sum_{j=0}^{N} b_j \right). $$

In the second step, the condition $i+j\leq 2N$ is removed because it is implied by $i, j \leq N$.

Comment: @SanchulLee thank you for your answer. Although I do not quite comprehend how you go from the second to last sum to the last one (the product of the two sums)

Comment: @ErikDz, The last step is more or less the distributivity. For example, if $N=2$, then \begin{align*}\sum_{i=1}^{2}\sum_{j=1}^{2}a_i b_j &= a_1b_1 + a_1b_2 + a_2b_1 + a_2b_2\\&= a_1(b_1 + b_2) + a_2(b_1 + b_2)= (a_1 + a_2)(b_1 + b_2)= \left(\sum_{i=1}^{2}a_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{2}b_j\right).\end{align*}